# Altivec Programming Resource

Tags: sse, simd, powerpc, altivec

Would be required to port some programming codes on Windows onto PowerPC. The codes would need some kind of optimisation and require the use to Altivec programming.

Would like to ask where to find a good beginner guide to Altivec and any SIMD programming if they would be similar to SSE?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should still be able to find PowerPC and AltiVec resources on [motorola.com](http://motorola.com), [ibm.com](http://ibm.com) and [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). Also search the `[altivec]` tag on StackOverflow as similar questions have come up before.

Apple has (or had) a very useful AltiVec->SSE migration guide that you could use in reverse - a quick Google search turned up a copy [here](http://www.thomasdideriksen.dk/misc/SIMD/Accelerate_sse_migration.pdf).

Note that IBM calls AltiVec "VMX" these days, so you might also want to use VMX as a search term (in conjunction with POWER or PowerPC).

See also:

- [can't find materials about SSE2, Altivec, VMX on apple developer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22978362/cant-find-materials-about-sse2-altivec-vmx-on-apple-developer)
- [Common SIMD techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2156368/253056)
- [Porting MMX/SSE instructions to AltiVec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4351383/porting-mmx-sse-instructions-to-altivec)

Comment: Thanks for the resources and links you have mentioned!